# well-known routes Kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, kubernetes

Hello I'am new on K8S and react typescript app,
I'am trying to deploy my react application with typescript, i have an error in Kubernetes deployment

```
Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
```

where should I put the well-known routes /.well-known/live and /.well-known/ready ? and what should I write for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where should I put the well-known routes /.well-known/live and
> /.well-known/ready ? and what should I write for it ?

No need for it if you are serving index from your container with Nginx/Apache it will work in that case you need to update the K8s YAML config and update `HTTP probe` path to just `/` probaly so when K8s check it's hit to `root(index.html)` main page of your react app.

**Ways to mitigate**

> Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404

This clearly means **Kubernetes** failed to verify or check the health of deployment in K8s.

in your error status code is : **404**

which means it was not able to get or hit the **HTTP** endpoint.

i am not sure how your route works and application is configured however this is the simplest HTTP option you could use.

```
app.get('/live',(req,res)=> {
  res.send ("OK");
});
```

K8s periodically check the HTTP status on this endpoint that you have configured using YAML config file.

**Nginx checks**

If you are deploying the separate **Frontend** pod and can not keep **HTTP endpoint** in container

You can use the default endpoint of `Apache/Nginx` as liveness probe just like `/` so by default **Nginx** or **Apache** `return 200` on `/`

**Or else**

you can also give any HTML file name from your code, `/index-live.html` so when K8s will check `/live` endpoint frontend container will serve html file with status code **200**.